# Multiple files upload jsp & servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, multiple-file-upload

**HTML code:**

```
<form action="test" method="post">
  Select files: <input type="file" id="myfiles" name="myfiles" multiple>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Servlet code:**

```
@WebServlet("/test")
@MultipartConfig
public class test extends HttpServlet {
  List < FileItem > multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
}
```

**Error :**

> httpservletrequest cannot be converted to requestcontext

Comment: If the below answer helped you, accept it or leave a comment on what went wrong, for a better answer. It helps the future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Mention `enctype` in your `<form>`

```
<form action="test" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```